# Chrome Possible Bug: Multiple Select element on page causes css transitions to trigger on page load

Tags: css, google-chrome, multi-select

I have run into a very weird situation.
My pages have a sliding panel that is closed by default using CSS transform.  There is also a css transition applied to it.
When I have a select element (with "multiple" attribute turned on), the css transition fires on page load, sliding from transformX(0) to what should be my default of transformX(100%).
Another weird thing is that if I copy my css to a style element instead of an external link, the problem goes away.
The problem only occurs on Chrome (I have version 51, on MAC)
I tried to set up a fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/jejq5s63/, but the problem will not show up there either, even with my css linked to externally.
Here is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.uvm.edu/~enewbury/fiddle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <aside></aside>

    <select multiple>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
        <option value="3" selected="selected">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5" selected="selected">5</option>
        <option value="6" selected="selected">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS (remember, it only causes the glitch when linked to externally)

```
aside{
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition: transform .6s; 
}
```

Here's a gif of what it does.
[Gif of animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc3DQ.gif)

Comment: after some research, looks like this is a bug in chrome after all.  Just added a class to the body on load so that it is hidden until doc is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar effect. 
I have noticed it only occurs when the `<select>` element has a `selected` state in one of the `option`s.

If this is not the case, the transition does not take effect.